# Tls 1.2 OR Tls 1.0 with .net framework 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, ssl

I have a .net 4.0 windows service that communicates between two different systems. One is service now, one is a messaging bus.

Service now is forcing tls 1.2 (as they should). We updated our code to use 1.1 or 1.2 by adding ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

The problem, the message bus is old and uses 1.0.

Is there a way to support both? If I upgrade to .net 4.7 will it work for any and all protocols?

Thanks

Comment: You can set the "per call" security protocol in 4.6 or later (if I'm not mistaken). Earlier systems have a system wide security protocol. You ask "Will it work...?". Try and find out....

Comment: `The .NET Framework 4.6 includes a new security feature that blocks insecure cipher and hashing algorithms for connections.`. Thar would block TLS1.0...

Comment: There is a way to avoid this behaviour: [ServicePontManager](https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/help/3069494/cannot-connect-to-a-server-by-using-the-servicepointmanager-or-sslstre).

Comment: I will look into this last suggestion

Comment: Your edit ("We updated our code to use 1.1 or 1.2") does not match what Microsoft suggestshttps://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `TLS1.2` is not supported by the server it will try `TLS1.1`, if `TLS1.1` is not supported by the server it will try `TLS1.0`. This will allow you to use the best protocol and fall back if the server doesn't support it, as is your case.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =  
    SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
    (SecurityProtocolType)768 | 
    (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

> Is there a way to support both? If I upgrade to .net 4.7 will it work
>   for any and all protocols?

Yes (*any and all* as far as your question is concerned) , I believe .Net 4.5 and up you can do this...

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work either. Seems like .net framework upgrade may be the best option.

Comment: even upgrading to .net 4.7 didn't work. I tried with and without specifying the SecurityProtocol.

Comment: @mtnNerds I've used this in multiple applications. I know it works. For one of my situations, I was using a third party service that updated their production API to use TLS1.2 but their development API still used TLS1.1... in another situation we used a third party service that upgraded to TLS1.2 and we had an internal service to mock their service for testing and it used TLS1.0. In both situations this worked.

Comment: @mtnNerds What are the errors you get? And where do you set the ServicePointManger.SecurityProtocol in your process?

Comment: I placed the SecurityProtocol code in the Program.Main before it instantiates the class the makes service calls.

This uses the NeuronEsb.ClientApi nuget package to subscribe to the messaging bus. The code is Subscriber.onRecieve and Subscriber.Connect(). The web.config contains the url and id of  the task we are subscribing too. No errors but when we view the events in the bus it says no subscribers found. If I roll the code back and remove SecurityProtocol to add tls 1.2, it works for the bus but fails for Service Now. "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Comment: This turned out to be something else for the Neuron code not subscribing. Marked this answer correct. Appreciate the help.